# How much can water be compressed?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, water, estimation, phase-diagram

How much can liquid water be compressed?

I mean the maximum achieved in practice and the maximum achievable in theory.

Say for example one liter of water at 4 degrees Celsius.
Can it be compressed to fit in half a liter?

Are there any applications for compressed water?

Comment: Ice-X is more than twice as dense as liquid water.

Comment: Maximum compression would occur if you dropped water into a black hole, but I'm assuming that's not the answer you are looking for.

Comment: See also [How strong is the force of ice expanding when freezing?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/653700/how-strong-is-the-force-of-ice-expanding-when-freezing/653703#653703), which gets into a similar progression of phase changes to obtain a low specific volume.

Answer (score 2):

If you were to put a solar mass of water together, it could compress itself to the density of a white dwarf star, $\approx 10^9 kg/m^3$. Basically an oxygen white dwarf (a known sort of star) with a bit of hydrogen included.

Answer (score 0):

The ocean tries to compress water a LOT at the deepest part, over 700 bars/10,000 psi. It stays a liquid at about 4 degrees centigrade.
This shows the incredible property of water - that it is densest as a liquid not a solid. If it did not have this property, then ice would not float, and our oceans would freeze from the bottom up.
If you put water in a black hole, it would not decompress back to water when you took it out, because the atoms have been destroyed.